# Recommended way to do getters and setters

Tags: go, struct, getter-setter

I have a project which will be written in go and it will have over 30 fields within a struct that will need to be validated before the value is allowed to be set.

In python I would probably use descriptors or at least properties to do this to prevent as much boiler plate as possible.

My question is what generally is the best way to do this in go?  Is it convention just to have lower case vars within the struct and have get and sets functions for each property or is there a better way to do this to prevent boiler plate code?

Answer (score 6):

From the [go docs](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#Getters):

> Go doesn't provide automatic support for getters and setters. There's nothing wrong with providing getters and setters yourself, and it's often appropriate to do so, but it's neither idiomatic nor necessary to put Get into the getter's name. If you have a field called owner (lower case, unexported), the getter method should be called Owner (upper case, exported), not GetOwner. The use of upper-case names for export provides the hook to discriminate the field from the method. A setter function, if needed, will likely be called SetOwner. Both names read well in practice:
>
> ```
> owner := obj.Owner()
> if owner != user {
>     obj.SetOwner(user)
> }
> ```